# (Marginal) density estimation over a (Pytorch) dataset

Tags: pytorch, probability-density

Online, there are a lot of density estimation methods available that work with Pytorch. However, many of these methods only do conditional density estimation, or the data has to be low dimensional or in a specific form, etc....

I just wondered if anyone knows any marginal density estimation methods that work with high dimensional data like images; bonus if it already works with a Dataset class like TensorDataset!

I skimmed through all the repositories listed [here](https://github.com/janosh/awesome-normalizing-flows#-pytorch-packages) and other public implementations that I was able to find. Most are conditional density estimation/only shown with very low dimensional data.